# Adding cflags for a specific directory

Tags: c, linux, build, linux-kernel, gnu-make

I am trying to build a kernel in which i have to give some additional cflags which are specificed for one directory and should not be used by other.

So can you please help me?

Comment: Specifying `subdir-ccflags-y += [options]` in a kernel subdirectory Makefile will add extra cflags in the current directory and its subdirectories. Kernel code usually uses GCC attributes (set by the `__printf(a, b)` or `__scanf(a, b)` macros) to tag variadic functions that require with `printf` or `scanf` type checking (`a` and `b` set the parameter numbers of the format string and its first parameter), but those do not do full signed-ness checking on the function arguments.

Comment: thanks but its not working

Comment: Instead of giving a summary of "*not working*", provide the full details of what you actually did/tried.